# Some of Characters is not show properly in html form

Tags: php, html

I have list of all country in my MYSQL DATABASE. I get those countries by PHP in Html select tag. But few counties name is not show properly. I see there is a  **? mark** within the name.

I set my MYSQL DATABASE **Collation = urf8_general_ci**
and I use

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in my html form.

But can't see country name properly. Can you please fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try mb_convert_encoding.

```
$string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8');
```

helped me while I had the same issue on an oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL instance is not configured to use UTF-8 encoding by default from client connections, you will need to do this yourself.

With the database adapter of your choice, execute this query as the very first query `SET NAMES 'utf8'`, if you are using PDO you can use the `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` option